# Codeigniter Datamapper ORM issue with array and object?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I have a block code:

```
    // Creat a object
    $privilege = new Privilege();

    // Get all privileges
    $privilege->get_iterated();
    $privileges = $privilege->all_to_array(array('id', 'name', 'description'));

    // Get user privileges
    $user_privileges = $privilege->get_user_privileges(array('id' => (int) $id), FALSE);

    // If user has the privilege which is marked as 1,
    // otherwise marked as 0
    foreach ($privileges as $key => $item) {
        foreach ($user_privileges as $value) {
            $privileges[$key]['has_privilege'] = (in_array($value, $item) == TRUE) ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }
```

My problem:
**$privileges** contains all privileges in cms and **$user_privileges** contains privileges of a specific user. I compare **$privileges** with **$user_privileges**: If user has the privilege which is marked as 1 else marked as 0 then I parse into view

```
$this->_data['privileges'] = $privileges;
```

In view, I must use **$privileges['...']**(array) to show result but I want to use: **$privileges->....(object)** to do it.

How can I do that? Thank you very much.

Comment: Can't you move the filtering to sql land, only selecting the `Privilage` instances that are available for the user? If you, for example can return the `Privilage` ID's from `get_user_privilages` for the user then it's only a `where_in()`. Also, why the continious-integration tag?

Comment: so in this case, I can't work with object and still use array as above code.

Answer (score 0):

If you omit the `$privilege->all_to_array(...)` line you can still assign new properties on the objects created.

Just change the assignment syntax in your for loops like this:

```
$privilege = new Privilege();
// IMPORTANT! 
// Don't use get_iterated if you want to iterate on the results more than once!
$privilege->get();
$user_privileges = $privilege->get_user_privileges(array('id' => (int) $id), FALSE);

foreach ($privileges as $privilege) {
    foreach ($user_privileges as $value) {
        // the individual $privilage instances wont be cloned for the iteration
        // so when we add has_privilage property they will "remember" it 
        // when you iterate on the same $privilages object once again in the vew
        $privilege->has_privilege = (in_array($value, $item) == TRUE) ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

In the view now you can write it like this:

```
<?php foreach ($privileges as $privilege): ?>
    <?php print $privilege->name ?> 
    The user <?php print $privilage->has_privilage ? 'have it' : 'dont have it' ?>.
<?php endforeach; ?>
```